# How to force a host application to load a .Net addin's version of transitive dependencies

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-core, revit, ef-core-3.1

I'm developing a C# .NET Framework (4.7.2) addin and having trouble getting the host application to load my version of transitive dependencies. The addin is for Revit 2020 (also .NET 4.7.2), though I *think* the issue is generic to a .Net addin-host context.

In particular I am trying to use Entity Framework Core 3, which depends on Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions (here DI.Abstractions). Revit itself doesn't depend on EF Core, and if it did I could use `extern alias` to load my desired version. However one of Revit's components does depend on an older version of DI.Abstractions (1.01...) than EF Core does (3.100...). When EF Core is loaded, Revit uses its own DI.Abstractions dll, which causes a "Method not found" error. There are a couple other dlls that appear to have similar issues, but if I can find a way to force the right dll to load, I'm pretty sure I'll solve the problem for all of them.

Most notable of the things I've tried, is that I got this same issue working in another project, also using EF Core in Revit, by using ILMerge to combine Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection (here DI) and DI.Abstractions. As far as I could tell, because DI.Abstractions was only ever being referenced from DI, this prevented Revit from ever knowing about the existence of DI.Abstractions. In the current project though, this hasn't worked. The only difference I can see is that I'm using Sqlite with EF Core instead of MySql. Presumably some other chain of dependencies is being triggered that causes DI.Abstractions to load from another angle?

Other things I've tried:

- ILMerge

  - I tried merging the whole addin, but EF Core uses some reflection that breaks if it has been merged using ILMerge.
  - Three of EF Core's dependencies in turn include DI.Abstractions in their dependency chain. I tried merging all of the dependencies of each of these three libraries into the libraries themselves, as I did above for DI above. DI.Abstractions is still loaded by Revit.
- AppDomain.AssemblyResolve: This event allows a handler to find dlls that Revit couldn't otherwise. I use a handler to load some dlls from the addin folder, but the problem here is that Revit *can* find the dll, and it uses the wrong one. My AssemblyResolve handler never fires for DI.Abstractions.

Here's the tail of VS's Modules window when the error occurs (Name, Path, and Version columns). You can see a number of the dlls are being loaded from Revit's folders and are version 1.01.2.30427. EF Core wants (and has, in the addin folder) 3.100.520.27007.

```
Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.dll
    <Addin Path>\Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.dll
    3.100.520.27007
AddinName.Database.dll
    <Addin Path>\AddinName.Database.dll
    1.00.0.20284
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll
    <Addin Path>\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.dll
    3.100.520.27007
Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll
    <Addin Path>\Microsoft.Bcl.AsyncInterfaces.dll
    4.700.20.21406
System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll
    <Addin Path>\System.Threading.Tasks.Extensions.dll
    4.06.28619.1
AddinName.RevitUtils.dll
    <Addin Path>\AddinName.RevitUtils.dll
    1.00.0.20286
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll
    C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit 2020\Addins\FabricationPartBrowser\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.Abstractions.dll
    2.02.0.18315
System.ValueTuple.dll
  C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ValueTuple\v4.0_4.0.0.0__cc7b13ffcd2ddd51\System.ValueTuple.dll
    4.08.3752.0
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll
    C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit 2020\Addins\FabricationPartBrowser\Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.dll
    2.02.0.18315
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll
    C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit 2020\AddIns\PnIDModeler\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Abstractions.dll
    1.01.2.30427
System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll
    <Addin Path>\System.Diagnostics.DiagnosticSource.dll
    4.700.20.21406
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions.dll
    <Addin Path>\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Abstractions.dll
    3.100.520.27007
Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions.dll
    C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit 2020\AddIns\PnIDModeler\Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions.dll
    1.01.2.30427
AddinName.Styles.dll
    <Addin Path>\AddinName.Styles.dll
    1.00.0.20284
NetTopologySuite.dll
    <Addin Path>\NetTopologySuite.dll
    2.00.0.0
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.dll
    <Addin Path>\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Sqlite.dll
    3.100.520.27007
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll
    <Addin Path>\Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.dll
    3.100.520.27007
System.Transactions.dll
    C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_64\System.Transactions\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Transactions.dll
    4.8.3752.0 built by: NET48REL1
Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll
    C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit 2020\AddIns\PnIDModeler\Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.dll
    1.01.2.30427
System.Threading.Tasks.dll
    C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Threading.Tasks\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b03f5f7f11d50a3a\System.Threading.Tasks.dll
    4.08.3752.0
Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.dll
    C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit 2020\AddIns\PnIDModeler\Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory.dll
    1.01.2.30427
Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll
    C:\Program Files\Autodesk\Revit 2020\AddIns\PnIDModeler\Microsoft.Extensions.Options.dll
    1.01.2.30427
```

EDIT
Another thing I tried. When the addin command is run (so before the offending dlls are loaded), I loop through all dll files in the addin's folder and load them with `Assembly.LoadFrom`. Revit still loads and uses the old DI.Abstractions, among others, from its own files. I end up with both versions of the dlls being loaded, but the old one is used instead of the new one.

Comment: I don't know if you've ever figured this out, but the reason it loads the wrong assembly is because those Revit plugins/components don't consider the version of the requested assembly. The request is for a newer version than they have, but as it doesn't care it will simply return the older one in their own folders. You can work around this by preloading the version you need (the plugins check if there's already one loaded, for some reason) but then you can't have newer versions yourself.

Answer (score 1):

That is an impressive list of different approaches you have already tried. Afaik, Revit only supports one single `AppDomain` into which to load the .NET libraries, so I am surprised by some of the partial successes you describe. One ultimate and guaranteed successful possibility would be to [use IPC for disentanglement](https://thebuildingcoder.typepad.com/blog/2019/04/set-floor-level-and-use-ipc-for-disentanglement.html), i.e., separate the problematic part your add-in functionality completely from the main add-in running inside Revit exe, and just communicate between the external standalone part and the main add-in using IPC to achieve the required functionality.

Comment: I did come across the IPC route in my searches. I was hoping to find another way as it would require a lot of extra code and complexity to communicate back and forth across the divide.