# How To Use Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting Package In Autodesk Revit 2019

Tags: revit-api

I try to use `Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting 8.0.0` in Revit , but when i Use This package in revit . revit send error : `[![enter image description here][1]][1]` , and then i add this dll to revit 2021 , this success , so i change the package version to 7.0.0, run in revit 2019 , alos get this problem , so how to solve this problem , or below 2020 cant use this package in Revit

Comment: Looks like the error image didn't post correctly. I am getting the sense, though, that you will need to create difference csproj files with different reference dependencies to resolve the issue. Since your add-in is running within Revit, you will need to use the same version of any dependencies already used by Revit. There are ways around this requirement, but they have their own drawbacks.

Comment: Hello , i find the reason from stackflow , the error issue is revit refernce dependencies older than the package , the address of the article is : [How to force a host application to load a .Net addin’s version of transitive dependencies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62436069/how-to-force-a-host-application-to-load-a-net-addins-version-of-transitive-dep)

Comment: Were you able to solve it?

Comment: @egeer not easy solution to solve this  ,  before version 2020  use older project and use di older then 2020